# Replacing a virtual ground circuit with center tapped transformer

Tags: operational-amplifier, transformer, headphones, virtual-ground

I just bought a cheap headphone amp (those *47 Amp*). I aiming to replace the voltage-divider-virtual-ground circuit with a 12v-0v-12v transformer (ofc with rectification). I checked the NE5532's VCC+'s & VCC-'s max is +22v & -22v respectively but the circuit expects 12v-18v (so the max is -9v,+9v). Would it be fine if I use -12v&+12v instead? Do I need to change some resistor/capacitor values for the op amp?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would it be fine if I use -12v&+12v instead?

No .

- 12 Vrms values with no load goes 40% to 50% higher Vdc peak.

  - 1.414 times for the rms to peak conversion and 10% typ for transfo losses at rated load.

Stick with 12 to 18V max to avoid overheating or damage.

Comment: What if I use 6v-0v-6v transformer instead, would it be fine?

Comment: What does fine mean? Why not a proper AC-DC regulated unit?

Comment: Sorry, but from where I am, getting the right parts would take a lot of time + delivery charges.

Comment: YOu didn't say why you wanted to remove virtual ground and this is not intended for low impedance headphones. You would need x mF Caps to filter the ripple from a rectifier. Try to salvage DC power from somewhere